# URLLoader is sending post data as [object Object]

Tags: flash

I'm sending a URLRequest with a URLLoader and the post is being sent as "[object Object]".

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var parameters:Object = {};
parameters.name = "john";
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = parameters;
request.url = url;
loader.load(request);
```

When I look at the request the post data being sent is `[object Object]` instead of `name=john`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the parameters from Object to URLVariables and it worked:

```
var parameters:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
```

Comment: Then be sure to choose your answer as correct so others know that the problem has been solved. Good job figuring it out on your own!

Comment: +1 or thanks! stack overflow makes you wait 2 days before you can accept your own answers. yay!